# Does a country keep track of the visas its citizens are getting?

Tags: visas, passports, consulates

For example, say you are a citizen of Uruguay getting an Indian visa from the Indian consulate in New York. Do the Uruguayan authorities get notified of this somehow?

Comment: No they do not, except possibly if the two countries share data

Comment: In general, probably not, but in some cases, maybe.  Are you interested in a particular case?

Comment: Yeah! What about countries that only have loose or no diplomatic ties?

Comment: Is this specifically about your visit to Israel (as discussed in another question)? It would be easier to have this discussion about your specific situation than trying to generalize about all countries in the world.

Comment: Such as Pakistan and Israel?

Comment: Note that even if a country isn't notified what visas you're getting, they might still find out other ways. Some countries receive Advance Passenger Information for everyone flying into the country, and in some cases that can include the entire [PNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record), essentially an entire air itinerary. If you book a single ticket from, say, Montevideo to Delhi to New York, the US will know you've been to Uruguay and India from your air reservation (or passport stamps) even if they don't know about any foreign visas.

Comment: Yes @Zach Lipton this is regarding my trip to Israel